# Query Execution of SP while using it in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

I have a query that returns a resultset. And I want to apply filter and sorting on the resultset.
Can someone help me understand if I use the query in LINQ (I'm using EF 4.0), will I be able to get deferred executuin so that when i apply filter/sort in entity model, the execution happens only one time (deffered)

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Bhavik

Comment: Do you invoke stored procedure?

Comment: From scratch - yes. Also it is not correct to say that you're using LINQ to SQL in EF. When you query `ObjectContext` - you're using LINQ to Entities. Please add code for clarifying question.

Comment: Thanks @anatoliiG for correcting. The answer by James solves my issue. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the query takes no parameters, then yes, as you could make a view that calls that sproc, expose the view in your model, then query it.

If it takes parameters, then if you need the sort/filter done server-side, then I think you'd have to add a wrapper sproc (or modify the existing one) to pass in the sort and filter to perform (basically, do it manually, but at least server-side).

Alternatively, you could write the sql to do it server side (sproc results into temp table, then select from that temp table and apply filtering, still manually) and then ExecuteStoreQuery

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't defer the execution of a linq filtering to the stored proc in sql. The stored proc will be executed first, a resultset will be returned, you can then cast it to a list of your object types, once done that you can filter using Linq. 
You can easily cast the resultset to a list of your objects using **context.Translate<>**

Have a look to these links :

- [enter link description here](http://geekswithblogs.net/rgupta/archive/2010/06/23/entity-framework-v4-ndash-tips-and-tricks.aspx)
- [List item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321)

Of course the query (in your code) will not be evaluated until you cast it to a list, so you can concatenate all the filtering you want to your resultset and then call the ToList() to get the results.